# subroutine not reading from stdin

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, stdin

code is as follows

```
getstr:
    ; get a LF terminated string from stdin
    ; in: EAX = dest buffer
    ; out: ax = bytes read
    ; EAX NOT preserved, all other registers preserved
    ;op     mod     opr1    opr2    comment
    ;--------------------------------------------------------
    push            ebx
    push            ecx
    push            edx
    sub             esp,    2       ; allocate memory
    mov     word    [esp],  0x0000  ; zero memory
    mov             ecx,    eax     ; set the correct buffer
    mov             ebx,    0       ; stdin = 0
    mov             edx,    1       ; 1 byte reads
    mov             eax,    3       ; syscall read
    .loop:
    int             0x80            ; do read
    test    byte    [ecx],  0xA
    je              .done
    inc             ecx
    add     word    [esp],  1       ; increment the count
    jmp             .loop
    .done:
    mov     byte    [ecx],0x0
    pop             ax
    pop             edx
    pop             ecx
    pop             ebx
    ret
```

gdb dump shows that 0 bytes were read

```
(gdb) info registers
eax            0x0      0
```

does anybody know what is going on here?

Comment: what's the value of eax at the beginning of the function? should point to a valid memory address

Comment: Do not mix 16 bit stuff into 32 bit code unless you know what you are doing. In particular, make sure you use the stack in 32 bit units. That said, the syscall should return at least 1 character if you haven't closed stdin so you are probably using the debugger wrong. As @lurker said above you must at the very least reload `eax` since that has the number of bytes read and you need it to be `3` to indicate the `read` function in the next iteration.

Comment: doing that, and taking out the 16 bit pushes and pops still fixed nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two errors (assuming you use NASM):

First, `int 80h / eax=3` changes `eax`. Thus, the next call to that function has not the wished `eax`, but the code 1 for exit. Move the label `.loop` just before the `mov eax, 3 ; syscall read`.

Second, `test byte [ecx], 0xA` **doesn't** compare the values. It performs an `AND` and sets the flags accordingly. The zero flag indicates that the result of the `AND` was zero. Change the line to `cmp byte [ecx], 0xA`.